# Limit file upload control to only one file

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Is there a method to limit the xpages file unload control to allow only one file to be uploaded.

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `rendered` property so it only shows if the document does not have an attachment. You just need to add the facility to remove an already-attached file.

Comment: Thank Paul,  Just check if that RichText item has any embedded Objects.